# Checking values of pointers init'd through malloc

Tags: c

I am attempting to check and see if the head node of a linked list has been filled with a proper value. However, the pointer that points to this head node was initialized in another linked list using malloc, so now the value of the point is a garbage negative number, but it is not NULL, so checks to see if the pointer is NULL fail. Attempting to access this location gives a memory violation. How can I check to see if I ever actually assigned this pointer to anything, if malloc seems to give it some random value first?

The relevant struct definitions:

```
struct patient {
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    unsigned int roomNumber;
    struct doctor *doctors;     // linked list 'doctors' contains names of doctors
};

//  structure 'doctor' contains doctor's name 
struct doctor {
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    struct doctor *next;
};
```

Initializing and adding patients:

```
void addPatient(char* patientNameInput, unsigned int roomNumInput)
{

    // Creating and initializing the patient:
    struct patientList *l;
    struct patient *p;
    p = (struct patient *) malloc(sizeof(struct patient)); // allocating memory safely
    l = (struct patientList *) malloc(sizeof(struct patientList));
. . .
```

The code in question:

```
void displayList(struct patientList* tempList)
{

    while (tempList) {
        printf("\nPatient name: %s\n", tempList->patient->name);
        printf("Room number: %i\n", tempList->patient->roomNumber);

        printf("Problem pointer: %i", tempList->patient->doctors); // this will always print a garbage value

        // Doctor stuff
        if (!tempList->patient->doctors) { // Always fails.
            printf("Doctors: N/A\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Doctors: "); // this is the last thing to be displayed, before throwing a memory access violation exception
            struct doctor* dList = tempList->patient->doctors; // temp doc list
            while (dList->name) {
                printf("%s\n", dList->name);
                dList = dList->next;
            }
        }
        tempList = tempList->next;
    }

}
```

The line labeled with the comment "Always fails" is the spot at which I want to check whether or not there has actually been assigned a doctor type here, as opposed to the garbage value it does print. My apologies if this error is incredibly basic.

Comment: You don't show relevant code parts, but do you assume that `malloc()`'d memory is zero initialized? It is not, you have to do this by hand or use `calloc()`.

Comment: Wow, that literally solved everything, merely swapping malloc() for calloc(). Didn't know that existed. Post that as a solution and I'll mark it!

Comment: `printf("Problem pointer: %i", tempList->patient->doctors);`. Here the expected argument to print is integer but you give a `struct doctor *`.